# How to test if a parent pointer has been allocated?

Tags: c++

I have a `reset()` function that goes through a bunch of data and resets it.  One of these is a pointer to a custom class, let's say `Apple *a`;

The `Apple` class has a `vector<Seed *>` object, and a method `resetSeeds()` to go through and reset them all.

If `reset()` is called before `a` is allocated, I don't want `resetSeeds` to iterate over its `Seed` objects, since these aren't allocated yet.  How do I do this?

Comment: Initialize `*a` to `NULL`. Also `a` would not have "seeds" to reset if it was not allocated.

Comment: I don't understand, if `a` is of type `Apple*` then before it is allocated it doesn't point to a valid object, so there wouldn't bee a `vector<Seed*>` to reset at all.  If you initialize `a` to `nullptr` then finding ones that are not allocated is trivial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `a` to NULL to begin with. Then, in `reset()`, only call `a->resetSeeds()` if `a` is not NULL:

```
class Foo
{
private:
    Apple* a;

public:
    Foo() : a(NULL) { }

    void reset()
    {
        if (a != NULL) {
            a->resetSeeds();
        }
    }
};
```

If you're using C++11, switch out `NULL` in favour of `nullptr`.

Answer (score 1):

Initialize the pointer in the initialization list. That way it's set even before calling the constructor:

```
 class Worm
 {
      Apple *a;
      Worm() : a(0)
      {
           // a is 0
      }

      void setApple(Apple *_a)
      {
           a = _a;
      }

      void eat(void)
      {
           if(a)
                a->chew();
      }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Set `a` to `NULL` at its declaration, or in the relevant constructor if it's an instance field, and check for `NULL` before you use it.

I'd say it's good practice to keep any reachable invalid pointer `NULL`, and to check any pointer for `NULL` before you use it.